# convert vb left() function into c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have some vb code i would find it helpful if someone was able to convert it to c# for me. I dont really know what the left function does?

```
If Left(cboLeng, 1) = "1" And Left(cboLeng, 1) = "2" And Left(cboLeng, 1) = "3" And Left(cboLeng, 1) = "4" And Left(cboLeng, 1) = "5" And Left(cboLeng, 1) = "6" And Left(cboLeng, 1) = "7" And Left(cboLeng, 1) = "8" And Left(cboLeng, 1) = "9" Then
        Leng = "L" & cboLeng.Text
    Else
        Leng = cboLeng.Text
    End If
```

Comment: Seriously? You could post to SO but couldn't google "VB Left"?

Comment: google: VB left function -> millions of results

Comment: But does that code even make sense? I don't know VB, but it looks a lot like it's testing whether the first character is every number at the same time, instead of any number (`char.IsDigit(cboLeng[0])`)

Comment: this translates to Leng = cboLeng.Text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(It's not clear what `cboLeng` is here, by the way - it looks like it's being used as a string *and* a type which contains a `Text` property. More information would help. The rest of this answer assumes it's a string - otherwise, just use the `Text` property once to *get* the string value, and operate on that.)

The `Left` function takes an initial substring - but that code doesn't make sense. It's sort of equivalent to:

```
if (cboLeng.StartsWith("1") && cboLen.StartsWith("2") && ...)
{
}
```

A string can't start with "1" *and* start with "2". My guess is it *really* wants to be something like:

```
// TODO: Check for an empty string
char firstChar = cboLeng[0];
if (firstChar >= '1' && firstChar <= '9')
{
    Leng = "L" + cboLeng;
}
else
{
    Leng = cboLeng;
}
```

Comment: seems from extract given cboLeng is a control not a string...

Comment: beat me to it. but it should be `char firstChar = cboLeng.Text[0];`

Comment: @DavidM: I was editing to explain that. The code provided seems bizarre in various ways, to be honest...

Comment: @Matten: See my edit at the top.

Comment: So this code could be translated into `string Leng = cboLeng.Text`. That's easy. :D

Comment: Too quick off the mark Jon - thought you must have spotted that too...

Comment: @GolezTrol - sorry, only got the joke on second reading. Totally accurate. +1

Answer (score 4):

`Left` takes the left-most characters of the provided string. Equivalent functionality in C# is provided by [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx). So your code would start:

```
if (cboLeng.Text.Substring(0, 1) == "1"...
```

Comment: Can you follow the link and read the documentation? It's very clearly explained there.